# IdentityServer3 OAuth2 LinkedIn external login returning access denied

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, identityserver3

As of the last week our external LinkedIn provider for login/sign up has stopped working. When a user tries to sign up or login we receive a 'Access Denied' message back from LinkedIn. This is happening when we try to sign up through LinkedIn.

I checked on the developer docs and our implementation seems okay. We have not changed anything regarding our implementation for a while and it suddenly stopped working a couple days ago.

There doesn't seem to be any information available about things being changed in LinkedIn's api or docs or any way to contact their support.

Anyone else currently experiencing this or suggestion a way to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes, we are also facing the same issue and receive message "Access Denied".

Comment: Hi Leonard, did you find any work around for Oauth2 external login with linkedin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade your .net frame work version or update the security protocol Tls1.2.
For a quick fix add the following code under ConfigureOuath method.

> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. For OWIN users, please add the above line in ConfigureAuth within your Startup.Auth.cs